# How to run MsTest tests on Hudson-CI?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, hudson, mstest

The MsTest plugin for Hudson-CI just parses reports for tests that were already run somewhere else.
To generate those reports I think I have to alter the MsBuild scripts to force the tests to run after the build.
I have found [some](http://scottlaw.knot.org/blog/?p=400) [articles](http://geekswithblogs.net/michaelstephenson/archive/2007/04/27/112031.aspx) about how to do that, but both of them don't tell me where to include such tags.
I know that every `.csproj` file is a MsBuild script, but they refer to a specific project within the solution. 
Is there any global MsBuild script where I could include those tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to run the tests after the build is complete in your Hudson job, as you mentioned. You can run the tests from the command-line by adding a "Execute Windows batch command" step after the build step in your Hudson job. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx) article for more information on running the tests from the command-line.